# Structure Fortran derived types in separate file

Tags: fortran

I have the following program.

```
program main

type mytype
  integer :: a
  integer :: b
end type

type(mytype), dimension(10,10) :: data
common data

... rest of source code ...

end program
```

I would like to move type mytype definition to a separate file, but the type will be used across all subroutines. How can that be achieved? Do I have to put the type definition in common?

Regarding the data array defined as common, is it possible to put such definition in a separate file?

The objective would be to something like this (in C), i.e. group all global data in a file and all type definitions in a header.

**main.c**

```c
#include <customtypes.h>
#include <global.h>


main() {
    ...
}
```

**global.c**

```c
#include <customtypes.h>

struct mytype data[10][10];
```

**customtypes.h**:

```
struct myType {
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

**global.h**:

```c
extern struct mytype data[10][10];
```

Comment: You could use a module. For more details about Fortran modules, see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fortran/fortran_modules.htm

Comment: Thanks it looks it is what I need.

Comment: Modules are from Fortran 90, which is no later than the code presented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Modules* are program units which are intended to be used in the manner desired.  Indeed, they are described by the Fortran standard as (F2018, 14.2.1):

> A module contains declarations, specifications, and definitions. Public identifiers of module entities are accessible to other program units by use association

A module looks something like:

```
module module_name
  implicit none
  ! type, interface and object definitions
contains
  ! module procedure definitions
end module module_name
```

There's a lot more to modules than this basic structure (and `implicit none` is of course merely optional), but a good reference book/other questions here will fill in that detail.

Let's look at a module suitable for the goal of the question:

```
module mymodule

  implicit none

  type mytype
    integer :: a
    integer :: b
  end type

  type(mytype), dimension(10,10) :: data
end module mymodule
```

In other places, the definitions and objects are made accesible by *using* the module:

```
program main
  use mymodule  ! make all public entities from the module available

! The entity "data" is available from the module, as is the
! default structure constructor
  data(1,1) = mytype(1,1)
end program

subroutine externalsub
  use mymodule
  implicit none
  print *, data(1,1)  ! We're talking about the same element of the module's array
end subroutine
```

Comment: You should mention that modules were introduced with Fortran 90.